# How to fetch data from iframe in sap ui5?

Tags: javascript, iframe, sapui5

I have defined an iframe in sap ui5. After the page opens user does something and after that i need to fetch data from the HTML page. In HTML page there is an element which has id "list" and i need that element only.

```
var htmlPage = new sap.ui.core.HTML({
    preferDOM: true,
    content: "<iframe id='frameAdd' src='url'></iframe>"

});
var dialog = new sap.m.Dialog({title:"User Picker",contentWidth:"20%", contentHeight:"20%",
    beginButton:new sap.m.Button({text:"Close",press:function(){dialog.close();}}),content:htmlPage})
```

I have tried below things but not getting anything relevant

```
htmlPage.getContent()
htmlPage.getSanitizeContent()
htmlPage.getDomRef("list")
document.getElementById("list")
```

and geting **access is denied** for `$('#frameAdd').contents()`

If you have done this please suggest me the right way to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iFrame is most likely served from a different domain/port/protocol. In this case, it is not a SAPUI5 specific issue, but rather part of the browser's security measures.

The [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) in browsers also applies to iFrames:

> JavaScript APIs such as `iframe.contentWindow`, `window.parent`, `window.open` and `window.opener` allow documents to directly reference each other. When the two documents do not have the same origin, these references provide very limited access to `Window` and `Location` objects, as described in the next two sections.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access)

The solution would be to serve the iFrame from the same [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Definition_of_an_origin).